# AJAX is not submiting data to php

Tags: ajax

I have a form which collects some data that data is then stored into local variables, which all worked fine.  I then decided that i also wanted to send this data to a php page on the server.

However when I added the AJAX code everything stops and nothing happens, this is built for an app using cordova and i can't seem to debug it.

```
    window.onload = function()
        {
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", init, false);


        }
        function init()
        {
            document.getElementById("btnSave").addEventListener("click",saveData, false);
            document.getElementById("btnGet").addEventListener("click", getData, false);
        }
        function saveData()
        {
            var user = document.getElementById("user").value;
            var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
            window.localStorage.setItem("user", user);
            window.localStorage.setItem("name", name);
            var deviceID = device.uuid;
            window.localStorage.setItem("uuid", deviceID);
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/folder/add.php",
            data: {
                   user : user,
                   name : name,

                  },
                     success: function(response){                       
                    alert("Thank you your information has been saved"); 
                    }

                  });   
        }
```

And the form

```
      <label>Username:</label>
 <input name="user" type="text" placeholder="" id="user" class="stored form-control">

 <label>Name:</label>
 <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="" id="name" class="stored form-control">


 <button id="btnSave">Save Data</button><br />
```

Comment: Have you got error messages in the console ? As far as I can see, I think there's an error somewhere before ajax call. Try with a try/catch or keeping just the ajax call.

Comment: An other thing (nothing to do with your bug) you should use valid JS object using (with key between double quotes and no comma after the last item): ```$.ajax({
    "type": "POST",
    "url": "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/folder/add.php",
    "data": {
        "user" : user,
        "name" : name
    },
    "success": function(response) {
        alert("Thank you your information has been saved"); 
    }
});```

Comment: The code before the ajax works fine and saves the information to local storage like its supposed to, its only when i add the ajax code its that it stops working.

Comment: I use to write ajax calls like that instead: ```$.ajax("http://www.mydomain.co.uk/folder/add.php", {
    "type": "POST",
    "data": {
     "user" : user,
        "name" : name
    },
    "success": function (response) {
        alert("Thank you your information has been saved");
    }
});``` but I don't think your problem comes from this different syntax. So, have you got errors in the console ? It would be the easiest think to verify. Over all, is jquery present on your page (is ```$``` defined ?)  and working ?